# How to fix Athena GetWorkGroup permission error while accessing the console

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-athena, aws-iam-policy

I created an access policy based on least privileges so that the user is only able to run queries in an Athena workgroup, called "finance-analyst-dev":

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "S3Permissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-finance-0123456789123-analytics-dev",
        "arn:aws:s3:::datalake-finance-0123456789123-analytics-dev/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AthenaPermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "athena:StartQueryExecution",
        "athena:GetQueryExecution",
        "athena:GetQueryResults",
        "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
        "athena:GetWorkGroup",
        "athena:CreateNamedQuery",
        "athena:DeleteNamedQuery",
        "athena:GetNamedQuery",
        "athena:ListNamedQueries",
        "athena:BatchGetNamedQuery",
        "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution",
        "athena:UpdateNamedQuery",
        "athena:ListWorkGroups"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:0123456789123:workgroup/finance-analyst-dev"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GluePermissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "glue:GetDatabases",
        "glue:GetTables",
        "glue:GetTable",
        "glue:GetPartitions"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:0123456789123:catalog",
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:0123456789123:database/finance-analytics-dev",
        "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:0123456789123:table/finance-analytics-dev/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When accessing the console, the user continues to be informed that he cannot execute the `athena:GetWorkGroup` action on the resource:

[image: Amazon Athena console error]

I wouldn't want this user to access the primary workgroup.

All other permissions in this policy worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [example policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/example-policies-workgroup.html) in the Athena user guide. Copying the content here for reference. There are a few entries missing on the Athena service level and Athena workgroup level.

The error you see may be related to using the **primary workgroup** as default. And you can override that in the settings.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
       {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:ListEngineVersions",
                "athena:ListWorkGroups",
                "athena:ListDataCatalogs",
                "athena:ListDatabases",
                "athena:GetDatabase",
                "athena:ListTableMetadata",
                "athena:GetTableMetadata"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:GetWorkGroup", 
                "athena:BatchGetQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "athena:ListQueryExecutions",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:StopQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "athena:GetQueryResultsStream",
                "athena:CreateNamedQuery",
                "athena:GetNamedQuery",
                "athena:BatchGetNamedQuery",
                "athena:ListNamedQueries",
                "athena:DeleteNamedQuery",
                "athena:CreatePreparedStatement",
                "athena:GetPreparedStatement",
                "athena:ListPreparedStatements",
                "athena:UpdatePreparedStatement",
                "athena:DeletePreparedStatement"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:0123456789123:workgroup/finance-analyst-dev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```